# Why Sun/Oracle Developers did design ConcurrentHashMap like CopyOnWriteArrayList?

Tags: hashmap, concurrenthashmap

I have a very trivial and basic question why ConcurrentHashMap was not designed like CopyOnWriteArrayList ? If you look into the source of CopyOnWriteArrayList, the code is like this.

```
public boolean add(E e) {
    final ReentrantLock lock = this.lock;
    lock.lock();
    try {
        Object[] elements = getArray();
        int len = elements.length;
        Object[] newElements = Arrays.copyOf(elements, len + 1);
        newElements[len] = e;
        setArray(newElements);
        return true;
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

Can't we write ConcurrentHashMap like this

```
public boolean add(E e) {
    final ReentrantLock lock = this.lock;
    lock.lock();
    try {
        hm.put("<Object>" , "<Object>");
        return true;
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

If we do like this, what will be problem, what are they(Sun/Oracle Java designers) trying to address apart from simple multi-threading issue ?

Why hashcode and hash function is designed in a different fashion in case of ConcurrentHashMap ? Why did not they(Sun/Oracle Java designers) follow normal hash() function which is designed for HashMap ?

Comment: The question is Why Sun/Oracle Developers did not design ConcurrentHashMap like CopyOnWriteArrayList?